# avahi-browse -a does not show any results

Tags: debian, networking, avahi

I have `avahi-daemon` running on a Debian 9.1 server; however, `avahi-browse -a` does not display any services in my home network, consisting of a single `192.168.178.0/24` network.

I can access all clients (tested with `ping` and, where applicable, `ssh`) and

```
server# tcpdump port 5353
```

gives quite a bit of output from my clients, e.g.,

```
15:30:07.206879 IP Client-OSX.fritz.box.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0 [20a] [9q] PTR (QM)? _services._dns-sd._udp.local. PTR (QM)? _http._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ipp._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _pdl-datastream._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _printer._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _scanner._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _privet._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _http-alt._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ssh._tcp.local. (847)
```

However, my clients do not see my server nor the other way around, but the clients see each other's services, e.g.,

```
client1# avahi-browse -a
+ enp0s25 IPv6 client2      SSH Remote Terminal  local
+ enp0s25 IPv4 my-printer   _privet._tcp         local
...
```

`/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`:

```
[server]
host-name=alexandria
#domain-name=local
browse-domains=fritz.box
use-ipv4=yes
use-ipv6=yes
allow-interfaces=eno1 eno2
# deny-interfaces=eth1
# check-response-ttl=no
# use-iff-running=no
enable-dbus=yes
# disallow-other-stacks=no
allow-point-to-point=yes
# cache-entries-max=4096
# clients-max=4096
# objects-per-client-max=1024
# entries-per-entry-group-max=32
ratelimit-interval-usec=1000000
ratelimit-burst=1000

[wide-area]
enable-wide-area=yes

[publish]
disable-publishing=no
#disable-user-service-publishing=no
#add-service-cookie=no
publish-addresses=yes
publish-hinfo=no
publish-workstation=no
publish-domain=yes
#publish-dns-servers=192.168.50.1, 192.168.50.2
publish-resolv-conf-dns-servers=yes
publish-aaaa-on-ipv4=yes
#publish-a-on-ipv6=no

[reflector]
enable-reflector=yes
#reflect-ipv=no

[rlimits]
#rlimit-as=
rlimit-core=0
rlimit-data=4194304
rlimit-fsize=0
rlimit-nofile=768
rlimit-stack=4194304
rlimit-nproc=3
```

Clients run Kubuntu 16.04 and macOS.

What am I missing?

Comment: Replacing Debian with Ubuntu-Server ´avahi-browse -a´ works as expected.

Comment: It didn't work for me on Ubuntu until I modified "publish-workstation" as mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

avahi-browse requires the `libnss-mdns` package and the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` must have in its `hosts:` line two entries `mdns mdns4` appended, i.e.

```
hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4 mdns
```

I also added multicast to the interface by first installing `net-tools` to get `ifconfig` and then running

> server$ ifconfig eth0 allmulti

Comment: Although this is indeed needed for mDNS to work within the system, the content of `/etc/nsswitch.conf` would not affect what `avahi-browse` can/cannot see.

Answer (score 7):

In order to make your server visible tu Ubuntu clients, in the debian avahi daemon config file,  change

```
publish-workstation=no
```

to

```
publish-workstation=yes
```

Next restart `avahi-daemon` service.

Comment: sudo vi /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf; 
    sudo service avahi-daemon restart # on my non-systemd OS

Answer (score 2):

After months of this not working on my laptop, I realised the issue was iptables... (In my case, had to check `iptables-legacy` specifically!)

Because I connect it to conference and other public networks sometimes, having firewall rules seemed sensible. But if those block 5353/udp packets, then yeah mDNS isn't going to work when I'm at home.

No clue whether this was your problem 4-5y ago, but ... this result shows up high in "avahi sees no hosts". Hopefully my comment is going to help someone some day.

Comment: So.`iptables` your problem, but what was your solution?  IOW, how did you fix it?

Comment: I've gone the lazy way and just flushed my iptables when I run into this, as I rarely actually do have a public IPv4 on my laptop anymore.

But if you want to do it right, AFAIU you just need to make sure your iptables don't block 5353/udp?

Comment: How would one make sure iptables does not block 5353/udp?  For those without any iptables-fu.

Comment: Off the top of my head, `iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT` to fix it right away. A permanent fix as always depends on distro etc. (And probably even iptables isn't the default anymore necessarily?)

Answer (score 1):

On Rocky Linux 9 (RHEL, CentOS) avahi-browse didn't show anything for me because by default mdns is not allowed by firewall for the zone "public" which is assigned to any wireless connection.
I had to reassign my wi-fi to firewall zone "home" by running:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=home --change-interface=wlp8s0f3u4
```

where "wlp8s0f3u4" is my wi-fi interface name. You can get it from

```
ip a
```

It should have a name starting with "wl"